# Problems when using sql case

Tags: php, sql

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqvJj.png)  im currently trying to solve a problem. i have a database with a table with , id co2_band , tax year, tax percentage in.

I currently have this code

```
    SELECT tax_year, CO2_BAND AS band,
    CASE CO2_BAND = 116
    WHEN CO2_band BETWEEN 1 AND 116 THEN'116'
        WHEN CO2_band BETWEEN 95 AND 10 THEN 'fdjhgkjds'
    ELSE 'here'
    END AS b
    FROM company_car_tax
    WHERE tax_year LIKE '2015-16%'
    LIMIT 1
```

my problem is between co2 values 50 - 75 i have to round up to the closest record how could this be done?

example data
so i have a database full of cars and there co2 values.
if i have a car and it has a co2 value between 50 - 75
then it needs to select the 75 bracket

Comment: exclude `CO2_BAND = 116` from the `case` expression

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What closest record means? Sample data and expected output would help a lot.

Comment: edited and provided data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try something like my code shown below. Notice that the order of the `CASE` conditions matters, so I rearranged the order to make sure that all conditions can be hit. I did this by listing the conditions from most restrictive to least restrictive. However, if I were to do this for myself, I would specify the conditions so that there is no overlap in the values. That would eliminate any confusion.

```
SELECT tax_year, CO2_BAND as band,
       CASE WHEN CO2_band BETWEEN 50 AND 75 THEN '75'
            WHEN CO2_band BETWEEN 10 AND 95 THEN 'fdjhgkjds'
            WHEN CO2_band BETWEEN 1 AND 116 THEN '116'
            ELSE 'here' END AS b
FROM company_car_tax
WHERE tax_year LIKE '2015-16%'
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tax_year, CO2_BAND AS band,
CASE  
WHEN CO2_band BETWEEN 1 AND 116 
  THEN'116'
WHEN CO2_band BETWEEN 95 AND 10 
  THEN 'fdjhgkjds'
WHEN CO2_band BETWEEN 50 AND 75
  THEN select max(CO2_band)  FROM company_car_tax where CO2_band BETWEEN 50 AND 75 group by tax_year
ELSE 'here'
END AS b
FROM company_car_tax
WHERE tax_year LIKE '2015-16%'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You are missing the OP's request: `my problem is between co2 values 50 - 75 i have to round up to the closest record how could this be done?`

Comment: if i was to add this into php is there anyway i could implement a variable into the select statement because each car has its own fuel type so has a different co2 band

Comment: On then we can have sql with what ever aggregation you want

Comment: MAX without GROUP BY?

Comment: sorry for the rubbish layout of things new to this ^_^

Comment: @CMadhu, This solution does not appear like it will work because the first condition in the `CASE` statement handles the first three conditions, so the 2nd and 3rd will never be hit.